# Database table design: How to use multiple tables to separate related data so that querying resultset is simpler or require less code?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a three tables as illustrated in the *screenshots below*:

The primary design objective is to separate the values in the `LICENSE_REQ` table: `TAX`, `INSURANCE` and `BENEFIT` columns from their description in the `LICENSE_REQ_DESC` table.

The below query returns the `TAX`, `INSURANCE` and `BENEFIT` columns next to their description from the `LICENSE_REQ_DESC` table.

*Query:*

```
SELECT A.LICENSE_ID, 
       B.TAX, T.REQ_CODE_DESC, 
       B.INSURANCE, 
       I.REQ_CODE_DESC, 
       B.BENEFIT, 
       J.REQ_CODE_DESC

FROM BUSINESS A INNER JOIN LICENSE_REQ B ON A.LICENSE_ID = B.LICENSE_ID

LEFT OUTER JOIN LICENSE_REQ_DESC T ON B.TAX = T.REQ_CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN LICENSE_REQ_DESC I ON B.INSURANCE = I.REQ_CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN LICENSE_REQ_DESC J ON B.BENEFIT = J.REQ_CODE
```

**Tables:**

`BUSINESS` - `Primary Key LICENSE_ID`

[image]

`LICENSE_REQ` - `Foreign Key LICENSE_ID`

[image]

`LICENSE_REQ_DESC` - `Primary Key SEQ_NBR`

[image]

And here is the `resultset` screenshot:

[image]

Is there a more effective and efficient method for separating data from meta data (description) for efficiently querying the desire `resultset`?

Comment: don't include the description columns in your `select`. You are not designing a table..only querying from multiple tables.

Comment: pluse uno for well organized and visually appealing question. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! I needed to be very clear so that people reading are able to understand what I am attempting to achieve. The solution above works but is this the more efficient method?

Comment: The schema looks ok. I don't understand what is your question. When you ask for efficently, what are your worries right now?

Comment: My worries or question is: Should I create individual tables for each required area. For example: A Tax table and an Insurance table, then make those codes primary keys. Rather than having all in a single requirement table.

Will this make it more efficient when it comes to getting out the data?

Again, my question is, is there a more efficient way to design the tables so that getting out the data is more simpler or efficient?

Comment: @UnaverageGuy: What do you mean when you say "more effective and efficient"? Is your objective to reduce the amount of SQL necessary to do those queries? Or do you mean runtime performance? Maybe you could take a look at [Oracle Table Clustering](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/tablecls.htm#i25478).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like your way.

Some developers might create a stored function like `get_desc(req_code)` and write the SQL as:

```
SELECT A.LICENSE_ID, 
       B.TAX, 
       get_desc(B.TAX) TAX_DESC, 
       B.INSURANCE, 
       get_desc(B.INSURANCE) INSURANCE_DESC, 
       B.BENEFIT, 
       get_desc(B.BENEFIT) BENEFIT_DESC
FROM BUSINESS A INNER JOIN LICENSE_REQ B ON A.LICENSE_ID = B.LICENSE_ID
```

But I much prefer the way you've got it.  Keep it all in pure-SQL when you can!

Comment: So should I have separate tables for `TAX` , `INSURANCE` and `BENEFITS`? Then have the `LICENSE_ID` in each of these tables? Each table will also have it own description table or reference it's description using a description ID from a single table?

Comment: Regarding the 1st question - no.  Do not split your license table.  In general, any time you have multiple tables each having the same exact primary key, you need to look hard at why they aren't a single table.  99% of the time, you'll find that they logically should be one table (although you might keep multiple tables for physical efficiency -- e.g., vertical partitioning).

Comment: Regarding the 2nd question, I would probably have separate tables for the descriptions.  That would clear the way to store additional attributes there.  For example, maybe you'll start to store a "tax rate" for each tax code.  It'd be cleaner to add that new attribute to a TAX_DESC table than to a generic lookup table.

Comment: Good point and this goes further to reinforce the idea that a single 'entity' should be housed in a single table. When the required attributes start diverging you end up with this big sparse table

Answer (score 2):

There are pro's and con's to the single lookup table method.

The primary pro is that all the translations are in one place, you don't need to go searching hither and yon to find each translation.

The cons are that you end up with larger lookup tables and usually more complex join requirements since there is usually a discriminator column included in the join, and you are limited to having the exact same attributes available for every lookup.

Right now your scheme doesn't include a discriminator column to determine from the contents of `LICENSE_REQ_DESC` which code value source the description goes with.  This can be a problem if for some reason their are `REQ_CODE` values conflicts between the `TAX`, `INSURANCE`, and `BENEFIT` code columns.

An improved version of your `LICENSE_REQ_DESC` table would be to:

```
ALTER TABLE LICENSE_REQ_DESC ADD (REQ_CODE_SOURCE VARCHAR2(15) );
```

Populate the new column with appropriate values e.g. 'TAX', 'INSURANCE', and 'BENEFIT' then:

```
ALTER TABLE CODE_LOOKUP MODIFY (REQ_CODE_SOURCE NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE CODE_LOOKUP ADD CONSTRAINT CODE_LOOKUP_UK UNIQUE 
(
  REQ_CODE_SOURCE 
, REQ_CODE 
)
ENABLE;
```

And finally change your query to use the following joins:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN LICENSE_REQ_DESC T ON T.REQ_CODE_SOURCE = 'TAX' AND B.TAX = T.REQ_CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN LICENSE_REQ_DESC I ON T.REQ_CODE_SOURCE = 'INSURANCE' AND B.INSURANCE = I.REQ_CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN LICENSE_REQ_DESC J ON T.REQ_CODE_SOURCE = 'BENEFIT' AND B.BENEFIT = J.REQ_CODE
```

Comment: Great point: The reason I did not include source/discriminator is because in production the Codes will be a primary Key, meaning Benefits and Tax or Insurance cannot have the same code. But this may not be the case and so your idea is spot on. I shall add that to the table.

Comment: The `LICENSE_REQ_DESC.REQ_CODE` looks like it already follows some hierarchical system based on the prefix, e.g. `201.x.x` = Tax, `901.x.x` = Insurance, `702.x.x` = Benefit. The proposed `REQ_SOURCE_CODE` would have not many (or no) benefits, but would increase the complexity of SQL queries.

Comment: @LarsGendner It might, but can it be relied upon?  The database certainly knows nothing of the usage relationship.  By adding a discriminator column you make that usage explicit.  Also it makes it easier to display a list of options for use in filling in the various code fields associated with the lookup.  Instead of having to know that 000.x..x through 399.x.x are tax codes, and that 400.x.x through 799.x.x are benefit codes and 800.x.x through 999.x.x are insurance codes you can just filter on the discriminator and not deal with the more complicated range filters.

Comment: @Sentinel If `REQ_CODE` already includes the information about the category ('Tax', 'Insurance' etc.), then a discriminator column would violate the [second normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form). And how would you assure that `REQ_CODE_SOURCE` will not contain the Values 'TAX', 'Tax', 'taxes', 'tax related', etc.?

Answer (score 2):

There is some interesting reading here (in the negative):

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/look-up-tables-in-sql-/ (although not everyone agrees with Joe Celko he always goes into depth)

Something to consider is your foreign keys. You can enforce a foreign key to this table but you cannot enforce that a tax transaction record may only use a tax description record.

Foreign keys enforce logic and can assist in generating an efficient query plan. When you are creating foreign keys that don't quite tell the whole story, it appears to indicate a design issue.

Looking ahead: Could this lookup table end up being extended to store many other types of descriptions? Could the distribution of description types be heavily skewed in some way? When you have a table whose purpose (and therefore content and cardinality) drifts over time , it can cause 'random performance issues'  when statistics get stale.